# Update a listview when a button is pressed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two listviews, one where the data is displayed and another where I insert data (InsertItemTemplate). When the button on the first one is clicked and data is entered in the database i want the other one to update.

This is how i tried so far:

```
<asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Add movie" OnClick="InsertButton_OnClick" />
```

And in the aspx file:

```
protected void InsertButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
}
```

When i use "Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);" my data is not entered, so that will not work. What should I use instead to get this to work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't have to redirect. To bind the second list, call list2.DataBind() on the same event, ItemInserted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the `ItemInserted` event and remove `OnClick="InsertButton_OnClick"` from InsertButton.

I believe the issue is because Click event is first fired and then later the bubbled event (ItemInserted in this case). The redirect terminates any code execution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually push/insert data to the database. Button only fires up an event, but all you're doing as a reaction is, that you redirect the page to itself.

So, you should do something like this:

```
protected void InsertButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InsertDataToDatabase();
    ReloadListViews();
}
```

While the method InsertDataToDatabase() will push the data to your database. It can look something like this:

```
private void InsertDataToDatabase()
{
    using (myDataContext db = new myDataContext())
    {
         Book b = new Book();
         b.Title = "Some title from selected textbox";
         b.Year = DateTime.Today.Year;

         db.Books.AddObject(b);
         db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

and your method ReloadListViews():

```
private void ReloadListViews()
{
   listView1.DataSource = SomeDbClass.GetItems();
   listView1.DataBind();

   listView2.DataSource = SomeDbClass2.GetItems2();
   listView2.DataBind();

   // ....
}
```

Hope you get the idea. If not, feel free to ask.

Comment: OP didn't mention, but I have the feeling he/she uses a DataSource control

Comment: @AdrianIftode, yes, that may be the case. However, I didn't offer him a complete solution, just wanted to give him the idea on how to achieve his goal. Now it's up to him to modify the code for his specific situation.

Comment: Yes, i am using a DataSource control, and the data IS inserted to my database, but to see it in my other table (listview) i need to update it, for example remove an item..then I see the inserted item.